# Erro Azure phpMyAdmin: Access denied!

Tags: phpmyadmin, microsoft-azure

Algumas vezes, durante meu trabalho desenvolvendo meu app no azure, me deparo com esta situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso o navegador chrome

Meu banco de dados MySql: `MySQL no Aplicativo` portanto só utilizo para uma aplicação.

Alguma sugestão de como consertar isso?

Comment: Meio que off: mas me diga, você acha uma boa mesmo deixar uma aplicação dessa rodando no seu servidor? Além de ser uma aplicação meio pesada ela ainda pode ser uma otima oportunidade de usuários mal intencionados tentarem invadir algo, não que irão conseguir, mas se você não tem experiencia com configuração deste tipo é bem capaz de você poder deixar alguma falha, tem muita coisa que dá pra resolver com aplicações diretamente em vosso computador, até mesmo o phpmyadmin pode ficar em seu computador e vc sincronizar com o seu mysql-server

Comment: Entendo sua linha de pensamento. porém as aplicações são simples com objetivo de hospedar conteúdo para estudo ou divulgação de projetos acadêmicos.

Comment: Não tem haver com o intuito do site, tem haver com segurança, invasores não se preocupam com intuito, cada um tem seus próprios motivos, até mesmo apenas "sacanear", o problema esta no uso de uma ferramenta o qual pode conter sploits ou não e na sua experiencia com o uso da mesma. Se notar muitas hospedagens que já contem o phpMyAdmin geralmente só o liberam para usar se vc fizer o acesso pelo painel deles, ou seja não é um endereço "tão publico". O entendimento de segurança não é algo fácil.

Comment: Ou seja usar essa aplicação para fins acadêmicos e aceitar a oscilação  quanto a disponibilidade ???

Comment: Não tem haver com a aplicação e nem com os fins. Tem haver com ser algo que esta em um endereço publico disponivel para diferentes pessoas, que poderá ser compartilhado, somando a possibilidade de sploits no phpmyadmin (dependendo se vc não atualizar ele pode aparecer algum sploit desconhecido ainda), vocÊ pode muito bem usar uma aplicação de controle de banco no desktop e sincronizar com vosso servidor (de preferencia usando criptográfica de segurança no mysql-server)... Como disse, isso não tem haver com seu erro, é uma situação off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL in App já possui um gerenciador, vc não precisa de um terceiro para gerenciar seu banco de dados MySQL no Aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os comentários do @guilherme-nascimento fazem sentido. Adicionar o phpMyAdmin na mesma hospedagem de sua aplicação é apenas criar mais uma oportunidade de ataque mal intencionado - é comum hacking bots testarem se a url `/phpMyAdmin` existe em qualquer website, se tiver, irão começar a forçar a entrada, mesmo que não consigam descobrir a senha, irão consumir recursos de tráfego e processamento de sua aplicação, podendo desde tirar a mesma do ar, até te criar um custo não planejado.

Comment: Como eu disse..são aplicações simples, concordo com a questão de segurança. Porém, existe alguma forma para corrigir este Access Denied ???? Este tipo de situação ocorre durante o dia sem muita previsão!!!

Comment: ou Terei de comprar o serviço pago do azure para criar um banco Mysql para minhas aplicações no Azure ????

Comment: Eu disse que seu App Service MySQL in App já possui gerenciador nativo. Vide a imagem. Vc não precisa por um phpmyadmin adicional.

Comment: Abre seu WebApp no Portal Azure, vai via menu em MySQL in App e lá terá o link para Gerenciar como na imagem.

Answer (score 2):

No geral, este erro ocorre quando o processo do MySql não está rodando, quando isto acontece, eu reinicio a aplicação e acesso o site ou mando um ping, verifico se o processo "mysqld" aparece no Process explorer eu tento o acesso através do botão "manager".

Uma das causas também para este tipo de erro, é ter mais uma aplicação phpMyadmin instalado, sendo uma nativa e podendo ser instalada via KUDU em site extensions, recomendo remover caso tenha, ou terá que configurá-lo manualmente.

Fonte: [Microsoft site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/09/08/troubleshooting-faq-for-mysql-in-apppreview/)